# Perturbative vs. non-perturbative approaches to a well-defined Yang-Mills theory in 4 dimensions

Tags: mathematical-physics, renormalization, perturbation-theory, yang-mills, non-perturbative

Another question regarding the [Yang-Mills Existence and Mass Gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap) problem (http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/yangmills.pdf). Does the problem require that the "construction" of a four dimensional quantum Yang-Mills be non-perturbative? I get the feeling that this problem is to make notions such as the renormalization group rigorous, and thus is perturbative, but isn't lattice gauge theory already mathematically well-defined? If so, why can this not be used as an approach to this problem? Essentially, which is the preferable approach as specified by the problem: perturbative or non-perturbative?

Comment: It is believed that the mass gap is a purely non-pertubative effect hence a pertubative approach does not work.

Comment: @TobiasDiez Why is this?

Comment: The reason is, that the mass gap is proportional to $exp(- g^2)$, where $g$ is the coupling constant. So in perturbation theory you send $g \rightarrow 0$ and hence the mass gap also vanishes. See for example, page 29 in http://media.scgp.stonybrook.edu/presentations/20120117_3_Witten.pdf

Comment: Yes, of course @TobiasDiez meant $e^{-1/g^2}$.